# True/False if a user is a customer without revealing the actual customer

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, private-set-intersection

I have a user A and a third party company B. I want to check if A is a customer of B.

1. B cannot reveal any information about their customer list to me.
2. If A is a customer of B, I do not want B to know *which* customer they are. They should only know True/False answer to wether they are a customer.

What sort of problem is this? I thought this might be a private set intersection problem but the definition seems to violate my second condition. Is this instead a Zero Knowledge Proof problem?

*"Private set intersection (PSI) allows two parties to compute the intersection of their sets without revealing any information about items that are not in the intersection."*

Comment: It would seem that what you really want is the cardinality of the private set intersection. You want to know is the intersection empty or non-empty. There are protocols out there for that.

Comment: @mikeazo thanks for the help. I found this paper https://www.ics.uci.edu/~gts/paps/psi-ca.pdf would that be a good place to start?

Comment: @mikeazo actually a bit of further reading seems like Kissner and Song might be a better starting point. https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/set-int-full.pdf

Comment: I assume that you also don't want to reveal the identity of A to B if they're not a customer. Because otherwise you could just ask B "hey, is A a customer of yours?" and have them reply yes/no. (Also, in practice, I'd be concerned about the possibility that you might just obtain a huge list of all _potential_ customers you think B might have and query B for all of them. Such a list might not actually be as long or as hard to generate as you might think. Rate limits could help here.)

Answer (score 4):

A 1-out-of-n [Oblivious Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) protocol would fit as a solution to your problem.

Oblivious Transfer can be viewed as an improved [Private information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_information_retrieval) protocol, because it allows that only exactly 1 item is retrieved from the database, without sharing any additional info about the database. In addition the "sharer" of the database ($B$) doesn't learn about which item ($A$) was retrieved.

If $A$ is **not** a customer of $B$ then $B$ should only return information in a way to make it clear to you that $A$ indeed is not a customer and not any information  more should be disclosed by $B$.

*Tung Chou* and *Claudio Orlandi* have designed a relatively easy to understand 1-out-of-n OT-protocol, appropriately named [The Simplest Protocol for Oblivious Transfer](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/267.pdf). The math used for this protocol is almost the same that is also used for [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

If you really want a computationally efficient protocol, then the OT-protocol designed by 
*Moni Naor* and *Benny Pinkas* ([Computationally Secure Oblivious Transfer](https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/ics/papers/ot.pdf)) is more appropriate.